# i update my flutter version Error in ruining flutter app

Tags: flutter, dart

i update my flutter version to last update and i have error when in running my app

error:

```
Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone x86 64 in debug mode...
```

Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_svg-0.17.4/lib/src/picture_stream.dart:88:26: Error: Type 'DiagnosticableMixin' not found.
class PictureStream with DiagnosticableMixin {
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_svg-0.17.4/lib/src/picture_stream.dart:192:44: Error: Type 'DiagnosticableMixin' not found.
abstract class PictureStreamCompleter with DiagnosticableMixin {
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_svg-0.17.4/lib/src/picture_stream.dart:88:7: Error: The type 'DiagnosticableMixin' can't be mixed in.
class PictureStream with DiagnosticableMixin {
^
../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_svg-0.17.4/lib/src/picture_stream.dart:192:16: Error: The type 'DiagnosticableMixin' can't be mixed in.
abstract class PictureStreamCompleter with DiagnosticableMixin {
^
../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_svg-0.17.4/lib/src/picture_stream.dart:167:11: Error: Superclass has no method named 'debugFillProperties'.
super.debugFillProperties(properties);
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_svg-0.17.4/lib/src/picture_stream.dart:171:30: Error: The method 'toStringShort' isn't defined for the class 'PictureStreamCompleter'.

- 'PictureStreamCompleter' is from 'package:flutter_svg/src/picture_stream.dart' ('../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_svg-0.17.4/lib/src/picture_stream.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'toStringShort'.
  ifPresent: _completer?.toStringShort(),
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_svg-0.17.4/lib/src/picture_stream.dart:266:11: Error: Superclass has no method named 'debugFillProperties'.
  super.debugFillProperties(description);
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'C:\Users\lenovo\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 896
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

> Process 'command 'C:\Users\lenovo\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 52s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Comment: Did you try to run flutter clean ?

Comment: i do that. but same errors

Comment: what is the version of your flutter_svg in pub.yaml?

Answer (score -1):

-- Run pub upgrade in the pubspec.yaml

-- Run pub get in the pubspec.yaml

-- Then run Flutter Clean

-- Restart your IDE

I faced similar error and that worked for me